# Stellar Account creation

Tags: accounts

Okay this is a very basic question. Since on stellar network you need to create account first by sending at least 1 XLM. My questions are:

1. What if I send more than 1 XLM?
2. Do you need to call any function in first txn to activate wallet or it gets activated by just sending an amount?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The account is activated by sending at least the minimum but you can send more. For example, when using Friendbot, it sends 10,000 XLM.